# ¿Cómo generar identificadores únicos con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un componente HTML con JavaScript. Dicho componente va a aparecer múltiples veces en la página (en el orden de cientos o puede que miles), y me interesa que cada uno de ellos tenga un identificador único.

Hasta el momento estoy creando los ID únicos (UIDs) generando un número aleatorio para cada uno de los componentes y asignándoselo como ID. Algo como esto:

```
var UID = "componente-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);
miComponente.id = UID;
```

Pero este método tiene problemas importantes porque podría darse el caso de que alguno de los IDs podría repetirse. Como poco debería añadir una comprobación para asegurarme de que no se repiten los IDs, pero aparte de eso ¿qué otro método hay para generar identificadores únicos? ¿Existe alguna función nativa en JavaScript que lo haga? (algo como el [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) de PHP).

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo manualmente? Porque ya existe una [librería](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) para generar UUIDs muy buena que implementa el estándar [RFC4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122).

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta. Es una solución válida.

Comment: Si la razón de poner esos números randoms es solo para que no se repita en una misma página por que no usas un timestamp + algo, o un contador + algo para hacer ese ID?

Comment: si guardas los ids generados por ejemplo en un TXT luego solo tienes que confirmar si el id existe y si no es asi entonces crearlo! con el mismo codigo que utilizas para crear IDS random.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Existe actualmente una [librería](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) para generar UUIDs que implementa el estándar [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122). Su uso es muy sencillo, solo basta con añadir la librería y usar los métodos `v1` y `v4` de acuerdo a la versión que se quiera generar.

```js
console.log('UUID v1:', uuid.v1());
console.log('UUID v4:', uuid.v4());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/node-uuid/1.4.7/uuid.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Aqui te dejo una función que utilizo desde hace tiempo y me va de maravillas para generar ids únicos.

```js
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}

console.log(generateUUID());
console.log(generateUUID());
console.log(generateUUID());
```

Comment: Añade la fuente para que el autor tenga los créditos que merece.

Comment: .. y podrías explicar la diferencia entre `"x"` e `"y"`

Answer (score 6):

Eso depende de lo que entiendas por *único*.

Usar una variable numérica, e incrementar su valor cada vez que la uses, es trivial, así como convertirla en cadena.

```
window.UUID = 0;

miIdUnica = ( ++UUID ).toString( );
```

Ya tienes unos cuantos centenares de millones de identificadores únicos. Cada vez que ejecutes `++UUID`, automáticamente se aumenta el contador.

Puedes *resetear* el generador cuando quieras: `UUID = 0;`. O usar un *prefijo*:

```
miIdUnica = 'prefijo' + ( ( ++UUID ).toString( ) );
```

O usarlo en una función:

```
function randomId( prefix ) {
  prefix = prefix || '';
  return prefix + ( ( ++UUID ).toString( ) );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fragmento de libro "JavaScript The Good Parts" (página 41)

```js
var serial_maker = function ( ) {

    var prefix = '';
    var seq = 0;
    return {
        set_prefix: function (p) {
            prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function (s) {
            seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function ( ) {
            var result = prefix + seq;
            seq += 1;
            return result;
        }
    };
};

var seqer = serial_maker( );
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
var unique = seqer.gensym( ); // unique is "Q1000"
console.log('unique: '+seqer.gensym( ));
console.log('unique: '+seqer.gensym( ));
```

Answer (score 5):

Otra opción es la siguiente:

Usa la fecha actual para armar un valor de identificación *el cual siempre será único cada vez que se genere*.

Para esta muestra, he tomado prestado el [código de W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp) y lo he adaptado para ilustrar mejor lo expuesto en el punto anterior:

```js
// Función "añadir cero".
function addZero(x, n) {
  while (x.toString().length < n) {
    x = "0" + x;
  }
  return x;
}

// Añadir control al elemento "p" principal de la página.
function addControl() {
  var d = new Date();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
  var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
  x.innerHTML += "<p id='" + h + m + s + ms + "'>ID: " + h + m + s + ms + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<p>
  <i>En el div de abajo, usted encontrará elementos<br/>
HTML de tipo "p" con valores de identificación únicos:</i>
</p>
<p>
  <button onclick="addControl()">Agregar control</button>
</p>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

Por supuesto, si se trata de seguridad u otra característica que debe poseer los valores únicos, esta puede no ser la mejor opción *dependiendo de la necesidad que tenga el desarrollador*.

Answer (score 4):

**`locutus.io`** tiene publicada en su web una implementación de [`uniqid en JS`](http://locutus.io/php/misc/uniqid/) equivalente a la de [`uniqid de PHP`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php)

```js
function uniqid (prefix, moreEntropy) {
  //  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/uniqid/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)
  //  revised by: Kankrelune (http://www.webfaktory.info/)
  //      note 1: Uses an internal counter (in locutus global) to avoid collision
  //   example 1: var $id = uniqid()
  //   example 1: var $result = $id.length === 13
  //   returns 1: true
  //   example 2: var $id = uniqid('foo')
  //   example 2: var $result = $id.length === (13 + 'foo'.length)
  //   returns 2: true
  //   example 3: var $id = uniqid('bar', true)
  //   example 3: var $result = $id.length === (23 + 'bar'.length)
  //   returns 3: true
  if (typeof prefix === 'undefined') {
    prefix = ''
  }
  var retId
  var _formatSeed = function (seed, reqWidth) {
    seed = parseInt(seed, 10).toString(16) // to hex str
    if (reqWidth < seed.length) {
      // so long we split
      return seed.slice(seed.length - reqWidth)
    }
    if (reqWidth > seed.length) {
      // so short we pad
      return Array(1 + (reqWidth - seed.length)).join('0') + seed
    }
    return seed
  }
  var $global = (typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global)
  $global.$locutus = $global.$locutus || {}
  var $locutus = $global.$locutus
  $locutus.php = $locutus.php || {}
  if (!$locutus.php.uniqidSeed) {
    // init seed with big random int
    $locutus.php.uniqidSeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x75bcd15)
  }
  $locutus.php.uniqidSeed++
  // start with prefix, add current milliseconds hex string
  retId = prefix
  retId += _formatSeed(parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000, 10), 8)
  // add seed hex string
  retId += _formatSeed($locutus.php.uniqidSeed, 5)
  if (moreEntropy) {
    // for more entropy we add a float lower to 10
    retId += (Math.random() * 10).toFixed(8).toString()
  }
  return retId
}

console.log(uniqid());
```

Answer (score 3):

Nativamente, no, no se puede. Tendrías que construir un método que adosara los ID a un espacio de nombres y fuera incrementándose con cada elemento.

En vez de reinventar la rueda, podrías usar el método [_.uniqueId de underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) que hace exactamente lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 3):

Si deben ser únicos solo del lado del cliente (o sea no necesitas algo criptográficamente seguro) puedes poner un contador para generar el id al igual que lo hace la función `uniqueId` de Underscore que comentó @amendadiel, y te **ahorras una librería externa**, entonces si revisamos la función mencionada, vemos es bastante sencilla (editada para quitar el *namespace* de Underscore):

```js
var idCounter = 0;
function uniqueId(prefix) {
    var id = ++idCounter + '';
    return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
};
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
```

De igual manera podrías usar un timestamp y un numero random si quieres algo más largo (aunque con el contador debería servirte):

```js
function uniqueId(prefix) {
    var id = + new Date() + '-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
};
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
console.log(uniqueId('componente-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los quieres para la UI puedes usar Symbol https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Symbol

Sin librerías, sin generadores de uids/strings

Realmente unicos

Con un equals rapido

Answer (score 0):

Sé que esta pregunta ya tienes varios años, pero en caso de que alguien actualmente busque una respuesta, aquí dejo algo que me pareció bastante acertado.

Navegando en internet encontré una solución bastante sencilla

```
const generateId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 18);
```

Al parecer funciona bastante bien y es muy corta, aquí les dejo la fuente
https://100.danielprimo.io/27-generando-identificadores-unicos-con-java-script-en-local-storage