# No se asigna el valor en el input desde la etiqueta script en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tengo una función *JavaScript* para generar números aleatorios, la cual quiero mostrar en un `input type="text"`, pero no me resulta.

La función muestra resultados en la console sin problemas, sin embargo, no me permite mostrarla en el `input`.

La función es `uniqueId` y la quiero mostrar en el `input id = "MUESTRATE"`.

Código (el cual marca un error):

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var idCounter = 0;
      function uniqueId(prefix) {
          var id = ++idCounter + '';
          return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
      };
      document.getElementById("MUESTRATE").value= uniqueId('-');
    </script>
  </head>  
  <body>    
    <header>
      <h1>Prueba JS</h1>
    </header>    
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="MUESTRATE">
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Por que tienes la lógica de JS antes del input, por lo cual cuando tratas de recuperarlo por su id aún ese nodo no existe y por ende no le asigna el valor; mueve tu script hasta el final antes del body que cierra y debería resolverse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba moviendo las líneas de las etiqueta `<script>` despues del `body`. Debería funcionarte de esta manera:

```html
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Prueba JS</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="title" content="Título de la WEB">
  <meta name="description" content="Descripción de la WEB">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <h1>Prueba JS</h1>
  </header>  
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="MUESTRATE">
 </body> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var idCounter = 0;
  function uniqueId(prefix) {
   var id = ++idCounter + '';
   return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
  };
  document.getElementById("MUESTRATE").value= uniqueId('-');
 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede usar `document.body.onload`. para todo lo que se ejecuta luego de cargar el documento.

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    // Acciones
}
```

> Nota: Pensé en usar `document.onreadystatechange`, pero vi que se ejecutaba dos veces, así que es mejor usar `document.body.onload`.

Se debe tener en cuenta tres cosas:

1. Las funciones (`function`).
2. Las variables globales (`var`)
3. Lo que se ejecuta luego de cargar el `body` (`document.getElementById`).

En este ejemplo sería así:

1. Funciones:

   ```
   function uniqueId(prefix) {
       var id = ++idCounter + ''
       return prefix ? prefix + id : id
   }
   ```

> Nota: El usuario [Carlangueitor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/258/carlangueitor), usó la función `uniqueId` en esta pregunta ***¿Cómo generar identificadores únicos con JavaScript?***, en donde él y [amenadiel (se cambió el nick a ffflabs)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18376/ffflabs), explican que *[la función viene de la librería Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId)*.
>
> - https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49990/13558
>
> Sin embargo, en *un [commit de GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/02ede85b539a89a44a71ce098f09a9553a3a6890/underscore.js#L318-L325)* mencionaban que *Underscore* fue importado de *DocumentCloud*, el archivo **core.js**, que inicialmente estaba en un *gist* con el nombre **gistfile1.js** creado el *12 de octubre del 2009*, hace 11 años, y la función `uniqueId` está en la *línea 337* de dicho archivo.
>
> - https://gist.github.com/documentcloud/208512/21e6aca40fb505b6e91bb2f3a7e63083a87fbb03#file-gistfile1-js-L337-L344
>
> Código original de la función `uniqueId`:
>
> ```
> // Generate a unique integer id (unique within the entire client session).
> // Useful for temporary DOM ids.
> uniqueId : function(prefix) {
>   var id = this._idCounter = (this._idCounter || 0) + 1;
>   return prefix ? prefix + id : id;
> },
> ```

2. Variables globales:

   ```
   var idCounter = 0;
   ```
3. Lo que se ejecuta luego de cargar el documento, esto es todo lo perteneciente al *HTML*:

   ```
   document.getElementById("MUESTRATE").value = uniqueId('-')
   ```

Esto último se lo envuelve en una función que se asigna al `document.body.onload`:

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("MUESTRATE").value = uniqueId('-')
}
```

Depurando la función `uniqueId` antes de dar el resultado:

```
function uniqueId(prefix) {
    console.log(
        "prefix: "+prefix
        +", idCounter antes: "+idCounter
    )
    var id = ++idCounter + ''
    var resultado = prefix ? prefix + id : id
    console.log("Condición: "+"prefix ? prefix + id : id")
    console.log(
        "idCounter después: "+idCounter
        +", prefix: "+prefix
        +", prefix+id: "+(prefix+id)
        +", id: "+id
        +", resultado: "+resultado
    )
    return resultado
}
```

Resultado:

- prefix: `-`
- idCounter antes: `0`
- Condición: `prefix ? prefix + id : id`
- idCounter después: `1`
- prefix: `"-"`
- prefix+id: `-1`
- id: `1`
- resultado: `-1`

Como el resultado está devolviendo `-1`, significa que el resultado es `prefix + id`.

Según la condición ternaria:

```
prefix ? prefix + id : id
```

Como el resultado es `prefix + id`, la variable `prefix`, que el signo menor `"-"` se está tomando como `true`. Además, observemos lo siguiente. Se resuelve de la siguiente manera:

1. `prefix + id`
2. `"-" + 1`
3. `"-1"`

Notamos la concatenación (unión) del *string* `"-"` y el `id` que es un número con valor `1`, y queda `"-1"`.

Código con `document.body.onload` (el resultado es **-1**):

```html
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function uniqueId(prefix) {
        console.log(
          "prefix: "+prefix
          +", idCounter antes: "+idCounter
        )
        var id = ++idCounter + ''
        var resultado = prefix ? prefix + id : id
        console.log("Condición: "+"prefix ? prefix + id : id")
        console.log(
          "idCounter después: "+idCounter
          +", prefix: "+prefix
          +", prefix+id: "+(prefix+id)
          +", id: "+id
          +", resultado: "+resultado
        )
        return resultado
      }
      var idCounter = 0;
      document.body.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("MUESTRATE").value = uniqueId('-')
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Prueba JS</h1>
    </header>
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="MUESTRATE">
  </body>
</html>
```