# No puedo cambiar texto de html con un archivo js separado

Tags: javascript, html

Estaba siguiendo un curso de javascript y llegue a la parte del dom, y vi como modificar la propiedad del texto de un div usando el getElementById pero no le cambiaba el texto, lo anterior que tenia escrito en el archivo js se ejecutaba bien hasta llegar a esa parte, despues de ahi lo de abajo ya no se ejecuta, probe poner esa parte del codigo en una etiqueta script dentro del div y si cambio el texto como debe de ser, pero al poner ese codigo en el archivo aparte de js no cambia, el codigo esta bien, ya cheque muchos sitios y esta bien escrito, ya llevo rato tratando de encontrar la solucion pero no puedo >-< ayuda
ya lo probe en microsoft edge, chrome y firefox y en ninguna sale el texto pero en la prueba de este sitio si sale el texto pero desordenado a comparacion de como sale en el navegador, no se que es, despues de esa parte lo que esta mas abajo ya no sale, ya probe poner ese bloque de js adentro de la etiqueta de script y sale bien pero cuando lo pongo en el archivo aparte no sale nada, debe mostrar hello word!

```js
document.writeln("hola1");
document.writeln("hola2");
var div = document.getElementById("pruebajs");
    div.innerHTML = "Hello word!";

document.writeln("hola3");
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Prueba 4</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
         href="Prueba4.css">
         <script src="Prueba4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="pruebajs">

         </div>
         <div>
            <div id="prueba1">
                <span id="pa">uno</span>
                <span>dos</span>
                <span>tres</span>
                <span>cuatro</span>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: asi es como sale en google chrome, firefox y edge]

Comment: funciono gracias C: , en el curso que seguia decia que se tiene que poner en head, y como en css puedo modificar lo que esta mas abajo de head me parecio logico que en js fuera igual, enserio gracias ya llevaba buen rato rompiendome la cabeza :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No se asigna el valor en el input desde la etiqueta script en HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328824/no-se-asigna-el-valor-en-el-input-desde-la-etiqueta-script-en-html)

Comment: Encontré esa @Trauma me parece ayuda a la causa

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estas intentando acceder al DOM antes que la página se cargue por completo.
Agrega el siguiente evento al código del archivo:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
   document.writeln("hola1");
   document.writeln("hola2");
   var div = document.getElementById("pruebajs");
   div.innerHTML = "Hello word!";
   document.writeln("hola3");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta mover la solicitud de tu script al final de tu body para que el archivo independiente .js se ejecute cuando todo el DOM haya sido cargado

```
<html>
<title>Prueba 4</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="Prueba4.css">
</head>
<body>
     <div id="pruebajs">

     </div>
     <div>
        <div id="prueba1">
            <span id="pa">uno</span>
            <span>dos</span>
            <span>tres</span>
            <span>cuatro</span>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script src="Prueba4.js"></script>
</body>
```